# Issue with dynamic web service URL

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, service

I have a service that I am using to make calls to several web services, each web service has a DEV, TST and PRD equivalent. Currently I have been making an instance of the web service and then swapping out some sections of the URL in order to change between environments depending on what is required.

I managed to get this working well but then I recently changed the code to use a database to contain the different URL's for the same services in different environments, however the URL's are now causing problems with the calls and I am getting the following error message:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at VRLSAPData.web.vrl.InvoiceList.ZB2B_WS_FUNCTIONS_006_SRV.ZB2bCustomerInvoiceList(ZB2bCustomerInvoiceList ZB2bCustomerInvoiceList1) in c:\Users\pigramm\Testing\VS 2010 Projects\VRLSAPData\VRLSAPData\Web References\web.vrl.InvoiceList\Reference.cs:line 81
   at VRLSAPData.SAPAllInvoices.AllInvoices(String environment, String companyNumber, String customerNumber, String dateFrom, String dateTo) in c:\Users\pigramm\Testing\VS 2010 Projects\VRLSAPData\VRLSAPData\SAPAllInvoices.cs:line 31
```

I am making calls as follows in code:

```
public static web.vrl.InvoiceList.ZB2B_WS_FUNCTIONS_006_SRV ConnectToSapAllInvoicesService(string environment = "tst")
{
        var sapInvoiceListProxy = new web.vrl.InvoiceList.ZB2B_WS_FUNCTIONS_006_SRV();

        sapInvoiceListProxy.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        sapInvoiceListProxy.Url = GetServiceURL(environment, "AllInvoices");

        sapInvoiceListProxy.Timeout = 900000;
        sapInvoiceListProxy.Credentials = sapLogin;

        return sapInvoiceListProxy;
 }
```

`GetServiceURL()` gets a URL from the database based on the name and environment passed through to it, I have checked and the results that come back are as expected.

I have tried debugging the code but I cannot find anything wrong, the URL appears to be correct and when copied into a web browser works as expected. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following Link

[Check this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/219e11a9-5778-477f-baf2-4cca245a6f74/possible-soap-version-mismatch)

Excrept from the above Link. May be this will help.

> The problem is that you are setting the URL property of the webservice to the WSDL url.  You need to set the URL of the webservice instance to the location of the webservice itself, which is something that is contained within the WSDL.  To find this URL, open the WSDL document in a text editor and look for the "location" attribute of the  element.  You can and should still use the WSDL url for graphical tools within visual studio, but it's important to make the distinction at run-time.

Comment: the issue appears to be as you state above however I feel like this could be better explained to others, I was able to find the correct URL's by adding a web service and comparing its URL that comes out before `sapInvoiceListProxy.Url` gets changed by my method call